# Adjust date format in googlesheet

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm importing excel data into a googlesheet.
But the dates in my googlesheet have as format the British/American format: mm/dd/yyyy.
Can I change that to the European (dd/mm/yyyy).
I'm trying to do this manually with an apps script, but can I change that elsewhere.
I adjusted my country and the Time Zone.
Here is the script:

```
`// Pas de datumnotatie aan
    function pasDatumnotatieAan() {
       var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var range = sheet.getRange("M2:M");
  var datumnotatie = "dd-MM-yyyy";
  range.setNumberFormat(datumnotatie);
  }'
```

Answer (score 2):

### SUGGESTED SOLUTION

It's possible to change the format in Google Sheets or by using Google Apps Script. Since the date values are in column `M`, you may try the following options to do what you'd like:

#### OPTION 1

In Google Sheets, you can do these steps in order to achieve what you'd like to do.

1. Highlight the data range where the dates are, which is `M2:M`.
2. Select **Format** > **Number** > **Custom date and time**, and select the date and time that you'd like for the column.

[image]

2. Choose the date and time that you'd like. In this case, `(DD/MM/YYYY)`. *Note: If the option that you'd like is not showing up, you may customize it by deleting the option and selecting your preferred format.*

##### EXAMPLE:

###### FROM:

[image]

###### TO:

[image]

#### OPTION 2

Using Google Apps Script, you can utilize this sample script as a reference for what you'd like to accomplish.

```
const myFunction = () => {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var range = ss.getRange('M2:M');
 range.setNumberFormat('DD/MM/YYYY')
}
```

#### OUTPUT

[image]

### UPDATE

Try to see if the [`onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger would work for you so that the date would be converted automatically when you paste data to the Google Sheet. I've provided some sample data in the same Google Sheet, but it should work the same if you're copying data from Excel. Here's the code snippet:

```
const onEdit = (e) => {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('M2:M');
  range.setNumberFormat('DD/MM/YYYY');
}
```

#### OUTPUT

[image]

#### REFERENCES

##### OPTION 1

- [Format numbers in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470)

##### OPTION 2

- [Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Yes I Know. And the code is ok. But everytime I import new data thé date changes to the old format.

Comment: I understand. Can you share how you're `importing excel data` to the Google Sheet? I'd like to clarify if you're just copying and pasting the data or if you're using another method. Also, is the account you're using a regular Gmail account or a Google Workspace one? Depending on the account you're using, I think a [`custom menu`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) would be best to simplify the running of the script in the event that it's defaulting back to the original format of the date.

Comment: Kindly disregard my last comment. I've updated my answer. Please check if it would work for you in this scenario.

Comment: Used the update, but no solution. The date must not be converted because it's in the dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: On the form in Cell M2 there is the format mm/dd/yyyy.
But in the the 'namebar' in the ribbon above I just say that there is the format that I recieved from excel and even more: M2 = dd/mm/yyyy hr/min/sec.

Comment: Although I would like to help you further in this matter, I don't seem to be getting the issue that you currently have. I've used Excel online and set the date format to both `MM/DD/YYYY` and `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS`. When I copied the data from it and pasted it to my Google Sheet, the `onEdit` function I used converted it to the date format I've set.